# FoundationPress (Foundation 6)

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

In FoundationPress (Foundation 6) I was wondering is it possible for the Top Bar rows to be full width with background colour but the nav to be contained in the 1200px rather than the default full width?

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Fabian, are you wanting the topbar to be a background to for nav? Also, are you wanting the nav to disappear when the screensize shrinks? There are a few choices to work with but we need a clearer description of your desired effect.

Comment: @ChrisO thanks for reply - I think I have it sorted now - just had row in wrong div position. Thanks again.